Offline, open-source, real-time speech-to-speech translation
Background
Looking to translate, in real time, from English to another language (e.g., Mandarin, Korean, Japanese, German, French, Spanish, etc.) using an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S10e).
Requirements
Looking for a Babelfish:

Set output language (side-step language detection)
Talk to phone in English (input) and phone produces audible translation (output)
Translate immediately button (to indicate end of input)
Real-time, or near real-time
Free and open-source
Works 100% offline

Software
Speech Recognition: A robust speech recognition model that can accurately transcribe spoken language into text. Preferably without using Google or Microsoft products.
Language Translation: For translating the recognized text into another language.
Text-to-Speech:: Convert the translated text back into speech, using a TTS engine.
User Interface: A user-friendly interface that allows users to easily start and stop translations, and manage language settings.
Libraries
Here are some open-source libraries that look promising:

Whisper
Sherpa ONNX
StreamSpeech

Ideas
I've tried:

3PO -- No offline mode.
RTranslator -- Couldn't get it to do basic translation with a single device and no bluetooth headphones.

Question
Have you successfully run an offline, real-time (or nearly so) speech-to-speech translation system on an Android device? If so, what app did you use or what app would you recommend?
